# Drools Class not found for evaluator definition

Tags: java, drools

I'm using Drools 5.5.0-Final and, suddenly, I have this exception

I put all the libraries again in my project, but the result is the same

```
org.drools.RuntimeDroolsException: Class not found for evaluator definition: org.drools.base.evaluators.EqualityEvaluatorsDefinition
    at org.drools.base.evaluators.EvaluatorRegistry.addEvaluatorDefinition(EvaluatorRegistry.java:136)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.buildEvaluatorRegistry(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:550)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.init(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:196)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.<init>(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:170)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.<init>(PackageBuilder.java:300)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.<init>(PackageBuilder.java:228)
    at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.java:34)
    at org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderFactory.java:46)
    at com.drools.optimizer.AppExpertSystem.readKnowledgeBase(AppExpertSystem.java:130)
    at com.drools.optimizer.AppExpertSystem.loadKnowledgeBase(AppExpertSystem.java:115)
    at com.drools.optimizer.AppExpertSystem.<init>(AppExpertSystem.java:46)
    at eventlauncher.OptimizerLauncher.NuevoEscenario(OptimizerLauncher.java:57)
    at eventlauncher.DemoPruebas.main(DemoPruebas.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load class: org.drools.base.evaluators.EqualityEvaluatorsDefinition
    at org.drools.util.CompositeClassLoader.loadClass(CompositeClassLoader.java:92)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.drools.base.evaluators.EvaluatorRegistry.addEvaluatorDefinition(EvaluatorRegistry.java:132)
    ... 12 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.drools.RuntimeDroolsException: Class not found for evaluator definition: org.drools.base.evaluators.EqualityEvaluatorsDefinition
    at com.drools.optimizer.AppExpertSystem.loadKnowledgeBase(AppExpertSystem.java:122)
    at com.drools.optimizer.AppExpertSystem.<init>(AppExpertSystem.java:46)
    at eventlauncher.OptimizerLauncher.NuevoEscenario(OptimizerLauncher.java:57)
    at eventlauncher.DemoPruebas.main(DemoPruebas.java:18)
Caused by: org.drools.RuntimeDroolsException: Class not found for evaluator definition: org.drools.base.evaluators.EqualityEvaluatorsDefinition
    at org.drools.base.evaluators.EvaluatorRegistry.addEvaluatorDefinition(EvaluatorRegistry.java:136)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.buildEvaluatorRegistry(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:550)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.init(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:196)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.<init>(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:170)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.<init>(PackageBuilder.java:300)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.<init>(PackageBuilder.java:228)
    at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderFaorg.drools.RuntimeDroolsException: Class not found for evaluator definition: org.drools.base.evaluators.EqualityEvaluatorsDefinition
    at org.drools.base.evaluators.EvaluatorRegistry.addEvaluatorDefinition(EvaluatorRegistry.java:136)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.buildEvaluatorRegistry(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:550)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.init(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:196)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.<init>(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:170)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.<init>(PackageBuilder.java:300)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.<init>(PackageBuilder.java:228)
    at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.java:34)
    at org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderFactory.java:46)
    at com.drools.optimizer.AppExpertSystem.readKnowledgeBase(AppExpertSystem.java:130)
    at com.drools.optimizer.AppExpertSystem.loadKnowledgeBase(AppExpertSystem.java:115)
    at com.drools.optimizer.AppExpertSystem.<init>(AppExpertSystem.java:46)
    at eventlauncher.OptimizerLauncher.NuevoEscenario(OptimizerLauncher.java:57)
    at eventlauncher.DemoPruebas.main(DemoPruebas.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load class: org.drools.base.evaluators.EqualityEvaluatorsDefinition
    at org.drools.util.CompositeClassLoader.loadClass(CompositeClassLoader.java:92)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.drools.base.evaluators.EvaluatorRegistry.addEvaluatorDefinition(EvaluatorRegistry.java:132)
    ... 12 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.drools.RuntimeDroolsException: Class not found for evaluator definition: org.drools.base.evaluators.EqualityEvaluatorsDefinition
    at com.drools.optimizer.AppExpertSystem.loadKnowledgeBase(AppExpertSystem.java:122)
    at com.drools.optimizer.AppExpertSystem.<init>(AppExpertSystem.java:46)
    at eventlauncher.OptimizerLauncher.NuevoEscenario(OptimizerLauncher.java:57)
    at eventlauncher.DemoPruebas.main(DemoPruebas.java:18)
Caused by: org.drools.RuntimeDroolsException: Class not found for evaluator definition: org.drools.base.evaluators.EqualityEvaluatorsDefinition
    at org.drools.base.evaluators.EvaluatorRegistry.addEvaluatorDefinition(EvaluatorRegistry.java:136)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.buildEvaluatorRegistry(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:550)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.init(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:196)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.<init>(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:170)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.<init>(PackageBuilder.java:300)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.<init>(PackageBuilder.java:228)
    at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.java:34)
    at org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderFactory.java:46)
    at com.drools.optimizer.AppExpertSystem.readKnowledgeBase(AppExpertSystem.java:130)
    at com.drools.optimizer.AppExpertSystem.loadKnowledgeBase(AppExpertSystem.java:115)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load class: org.drools.base.evaluators.EqualityEvaluatorsDefinition
    at org.drools.util.CompositeClassLoader.loadClass(CompositeClassLoader.java:92)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.drools.base.evaluators.EvaluatorRegistry.addEvaluatorDefinition(EvaluatorRegistry.java:132)
    ... 12 morectoryServiceImpl.java:34)
    at org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderFactory.java:46)
    at com.drools.optimizer.AppExpertSystem.readKnowledgeBase(AppExpertSystem.java:130)
    at com.drools.optimizer.AppExpertSystem.loadKnowledgeBase(AppExpertSystem.java:115)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load class: org.drools.base.evaluators.EqualityEvaluatorsDefinition
    at org.drools.util.CompositeClassLoader.loadClass(CompositeClassLoader.java:92)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.drools.base.evaluators.EvaluatorRegistry.addEvaluatorDefinition(EvaluatorRegistry.java:132)
    ... 12 more
```

My code is:

```
import com.answare.backendconnection.RESTConnection;
import com.answare.dataModel.ActionANS;
import com.answare.dataModel.CrisisContextANS;
import com.answare.db.QueriesDB;
import com.answare.settings.CTES;
import com.drools.utils.Event;
import org.drools.KnowledgeBase;
import org.drools.KnowledgeBaseConfiguration;
import org.drools.KnowledgeBaseFactory;
import org.drools.builder.*;
import org.drools.conf.EventProcessingOption;
import org.drools.io.ResourceFactory;
import org.drools.runtime.StatefulKnowledgeSession;
import java.sql.SQLException;



/**
 * This is the class that launch Expert System.
 */

public class AppExpertSystem {

    StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession;
    DSS_ANS optimizerDSS_ANS;
    Event event;
    RESTConnection restConnection;


    public AppExpertSystem() {
        loadKnowledgeBase();
        optimizerDSS_ANS = new DSS_ANS(ksession);
        event = new Event();
        event.setNewEvent(true);
    }
    public AppExpertSystem(RESTConnection restConnection){
        loadKnowledgeBase();    
        event = new Event();
        event.setNewEvent(true);
        this.restConnection = restConnection;
    }



    private void loadKnowledgeBase() {
        // load up the knowledge base
        KnowledgeBase kbase;
        try {
            kbase = readKnowledgeBase();
            ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    private static KnowledgeBase readKnowledgeBase() throws Exception {

        KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
        kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(CTES.RULES),
                ResourceType.DRL);
        KnowledgeBuilderErrors errors = kbuilder.getErrors();

        if (errors.size() > 0) {
            for (KnowledgeBuilderError error : errors) {
                System.err.println(error);
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse knowledge.");
        }
        KnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
        kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
        KnowledgeBaseConfiguration config = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBaseConfiguration();
        config.setOption(EventProcessingOption.STREAM );

        return kbase;
    }


    public String executeMessage(CrisisContextANS crisisContext) {
        try {
            storeInDatabaseCrisis(crisisContext,true);
            ksession.setGlobal("optimizerDSS", optimizerDSS_ANS);
            ksession.insert(crisisContext);
            this.event.setType("CrisisContextANS");
            ksession.insert(this.event);
            int num = ksession.fireAllRules();
            if (num != 0) {
                this.event.setNewEvent(false);
                return ("Run OK from Expert System");
            }
            return ("");
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            return ("Run NOT OK Expert System");
        }
    }
}
```

And the exception is in the method `readKnowledgeBase()`, in line

> KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder =
>   KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();

The only thing that I'm doing is to call to AppExpertSystem constructor :(
Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Either you didn't add the JARs to the CLASSPATH properly or the version is incorrect and that method signature is no longer available.

Comment: @duffymo Method signature? Which method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class is gone from the 5.5.0.Final distribution. It was present in 5.3.0 and 5.4.0 (jar: drools-core.jar), presumably also earlier.

org.drools.base and ...evaluators wasn't part of the stable API in 5.3 and 5.4, so using it was risky.

If you post how your code is using that class, s.o. might come up with a way to work around this mishap.

Class org.drools.base.evaluators.EqualityEvaluatorsDefinition is typically configured into the builder by including a line

```
drools.evaluator.equality = org.drools.base.evaluators.EqualityEvaluatorsDefinition
```

in a file "drools.packagebuilder.conf" in the working directory, your home directory or on some jar's META-INF drools.default.packagebuilder.conf, or on a file pointed to by a system property "drools.packagebuilder.conf".

Comment: Then, what I need to do? Delete the drools-core.jar?

Comment: This won't help. Your code has some reference to a package that doesn't exist any more.

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't a mix-up of jars from 5.4 (or earlier) and 5.5? As you are building from scratch, an evaluator would have to be defined for the builder and I don't see this happening.

Comment: In the 5.4.0 distribution there is drools-core.jar and drools-core-5.4.0.Final.jar. Make sure you don't have either one in the classpath when you try to build using 5.5.0, only this one: drools-core-5.5.0.Final.jar

Comment: Sorry for the delay to response. I have only jars of 5.5.0.Final.

Comment: Please add all (!) of your stack dump to the Q.

Comment: Is there a file "drools.packagebuilder.conf" anywhere on your system? In your home directory? Do you have a system property defined using this key that points to a file? What is on this file? If it contains a line `drools.evaluator.equality = org.drools.base.evaluators.EqualityEvaluatorsDefinition` then this is the "poison".

Comment: Uff!! This is the problem!!! I import 4 packages of other projects that have inside drools.packagebuilder.conf with this line!! :) Thank you very much!!